# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker is not working from IIS Host

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

I am using the following code to authenticate to Google using the Google .Net client library.

```
public static void auth()
{

string clientId = "xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
string clientSecret = "xxxxx";


string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" };     // view your basic profile info.
try
{
    // Use the current Google .net client library to get the Oauth2 stuff.
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                 , scopes
                                                                                 , "test"
                                                                                 , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                 , new FileDataStore("test")).Result;

    // Translate the Oauth permissions to something the old client libray can read
    OAuth2Parameters parameters = new OAuth2Parameters();
    parameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken;
    parameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken;
    RunContactsSample(parameters);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
}
```

I am using my own client id and client secret key.
This code is perfectly working when I am running from visual studio, but is not working from after hosted in IIS.

And I mentioned redirected URI in google api console is
http://localhost/authorize/

My IIS host Url is 
http://localhost/googleintegration.aspx

I am facing this issue by last one month, can anyone please give a solution for this..

Comment: what error are you getting?  Does IIS have access to write to %appdata%?

Comment: Yes, I gave full access to %appdata% for every users. and I got "Request timeout error."

Comment: Have you tried http://www.yourwebsite.com/authorize/ ?

Comment: I just wanna run localhost itself, and my hosted url is 'http://localhost/googleintegration.aspx' and I got this reference code from the following page 'http://www.daimto.com/google-contacts-with-c/'

Comment: I have been tracking this bug for a while https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/888.   The problem is that I don't have enough experience with IIS to be able to debug it.

Comment: yes, I am also facing the same issue, I don't know how to solve this..Can you please give any suggestion on this

Comment: Contact me http://www.daimto.com/contact/ If you can help me deploy it to IIS I will see if I can debug the Library.

Comment: Yeah sure, Just now I have sent a message to you through 'daimto.com/contact'

Answer (score 7):

There are several different types of applications. You can have a web application, an native installed application or a mobile application.  The methods used to authenticate these are slightly different.

The method GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync is used for native installed applications. It will open the browser window on the machine running the code.  In the instance where you are running it in Visual studio it works fine but as soon as you try to host it it will try to open the browser window on the web server which wont work.

You need to be using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow which was designed for use with web applications.  You can find an example [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc).

```
private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                    ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                },
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
            });
```

## update asp .net core 3.1 and .net 5

I also have a tutorial and vide which shows how to do this with [Asp .net Get profile information](https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/)

Answer (score 3):

(Reposting from https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/888)

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` is for use in an application that is running locally on an end-user machine. It opens a web browser *locally* allowing the user to authenticate.
It sounds like you are trying to use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` on a server machine, from within IIS; where it won't work, as it will try to open a web browser on that *server* machine - this will fail, and wouldn't be visible to the end-user anyway as it'll be on the server machine, not their machine.

I've not done this myself, but it looks like the [instructions here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) (for an ASP.NET MVC web app) might help.